# How to change the length of field from 255 to ilimit?

Tags: theming, hooks

i have a field in web site but lenght limit this is field is 255 , but client wants to puts more caractere to that field i want to change field [image: setting] from 255 to ilimit . any help please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can increase the length of a field within Drupal once there is data in the field.

Instead, go into your entity bundle and make a new field with a larger character limit.

Then, copy the data from the old field to the new field. There are several ways to accomplish this (programmatically with PHP; directly in the database with SQL queries; via database export and import; using [Drupal Migrate API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview); or with the help of contrib modules such as [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) / [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper).)

If there are not too many nodes of your content type, you might find it simpler to just copy and paste from the old field to the new field manually.

No matter which approach you choose, be certain to verify that the data is good in the new field before deleting the old field.